# What should we do about disturbing videos?

Tags: discussion, moderation, editing

The question https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/12212/what-breed-of-cat-is-this has been closed, but it has a link to a very disturbing video of someone abusing a cat. I believe that the OP was sincere, and just wanted to find out the breed of the cat, but a picture would have met the requirements as well as the video.

I only watched the first few seconds, enough to verify that it was the video I'd heard about. But from the written description (see http://kenny-glenn.net/), it would be distressing for most people to watch. So I removed the link to the video, and added a link to a site which has more information about the case, and has the video as well.

How should we handle links to disturbing videos? Sometimes we do have disturbing images for good reasons (e.g., to show an injury that someone wants advice on), but we can spoiler those. I'm not sure if I did the right thing in this case. I didn't want someone to watch the video accidentally and have nightmares, but the OP did make it clear what the nature of the video was.

Answer (score 4):

Your actions were completely appropriate IMHO, everything posted here is licensed Creative Commons; if you feel something needs to be modified and you have the rep to do it, make the change.

The link is actually still available in the edit history of the question, so nothing you have done is permanent.

The question is out of scope, the video does not add value to our site, and as a closed question with negative votes it should automatically be deleted shortly (*2-4 weeks I think*).

If you want you could also post a link to this meta post, in the comments of the question. At this point, I would not worry about it unless someone feels the need to discuss further and/or edit the question to restore the video.

Comment: Post was deleted by OP